# How to put lists together into list holding them as 'tuples'

Tags: python, sqlite

In Pythons SQLite documents we have the following example on how to put many values into SQL database:

```
purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)
```

But if I have one list containing the dates, one containing the buy/sell, one containing the stock tickers, one the amount and one the price, how to I combine them at the most optimal way, before I insert? I've tried looping over each list and just inserting them in the SQLite DB one by one, but that takes to much time.

```
dates = ['2006-03-28', '2006-04-05', '2006-04-06']
flags = ['buy', 'buy', 'sell']
tickers = ['IBM', 'MSFT', 'IBM']
amount = [1000, 1000, 500]
price = [45.00, 72.00, 53.00]
```

This takes too long:

```
for i in range(0, len(dates)):

    c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', dates[i], flags[i], tickers[i], amount[i], price[i])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to transpose your input lists suitable for `executemany()`:

```
rows = zip(dates, flags, tickers, amount, price)
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', rows)
```

The function pairs up elements from each list into a new tuple; each first element into one tuple, each second element together into a second, etc.

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> dates = ['2006-03-28', '2006-04-05', '2006-04-06']
>>> flags = ['buy', 'buy', 'sell']
>>> tickers = ['IBM', 'MSFT', 'IBM']
>>> amount = [1000, 1000, 500]
>>> price = [45.00, 72.00, 53.00]
>>> rows = zip(dates, flags, tickers, amount, price)
>>> pprint(rows)
[('2006-03-28', 'buy', 'IBM', 1000, 45.0),
 ('2006-04-05', 'buy', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.0),
 ('2006-04-06', 'sell', 'IBM', 500, 53.0)]
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> conn.execute('''
... CREATE TABLE stocks (
...     date datetime,
...     action string,
...     symbol string,
...     quantity integer,
...     price real)
... ''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10667bc70>
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', rows)
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10667bce0>
>>> conn.commit()
>>> for row in cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks'):
...     print(row)
... 
(u'2006-03-28', u'buy', u'IBM', 1000, 45.0)
(u'2006-04-05', u'buy', u'MSFT', 1000, 72.0)
(u'2006-04-06', u'sell', u'IBM', 500, 53.0)
```

Comment: ~~(minor note: the `dates` values aren't strings and the output doesn't match the dates in list ;-) )~~ Already updated :-)